# How can I get the latest record from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I'm using Pyrebase to receive data from a realtime database. Actually I can receive data directly, but I need only the latest record.

This is the realtime database:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the largest key (`4` here) is the most recent record's, here is how to directly retrieve it with [`pyrebase`](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase):

```python
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

last_record = db.child('input').order_by_key().limit_to_last(1).get().val()

print(last_record)
# should print OrderedDict([('4', {'input1': ..., 'input2': ..., 'input3': ...})])
```

[`order_by_key` orders in ascending order by default](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#orderbykey), and `limit_to_last(1)` ensures you only retrieve one record, being the last one in the query.

[**However there is a bug for calling `order_by` in the `pyrebase` library**](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/296). Fortunately a fork of it, [`pyrebase4`](https://github.com/nhorvath/Pyrebase4), has it fixed so ensure to use this one:

```
$ pip uninstall pyrebase && pip install pyrebase4
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works. Is there a mode to get it as a bit useable form, like 4 record input1 input2 input3?

Comment: You can simply access them as any other `dict` or [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), _e.g._ `input1 = last_record[0][1]['input1']`

Comment: I tried to use this code but I always get an error message

Comment: I solved it. The problem was that I didn't converted it to a string.